# How to get 'path' in the symfony2 php

Tags: symfony

Its very simple quesion about symfony2 ,but I couldnt find an answer by searching.

I know that I can get url in twig by

```
{{ path('fos_user_profile_edit') }}
```

but how can I do the same thing in symfony2 php source cords?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `router` service. In controller its ready to use `generateUrl` function

```
/**
 * Generates a URL from the given parameters.
 *
 * @param string  $route      The name of the route
 * @param mixed   $parameters An array of parameters
 * @param Boolean $absolute   Whether to generate an absolute URL
 *
 * @return string The generated URL
 */
public function generateUrl($route, $parameters = array(), $absolute = false)
{
    return $this->container->get('router')->generate($route, $parameters, $absolute);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, $this->container->get('router')->generate('fos_user_profile_edit') works well

Answer (score 1):

It is stated in the docs how you do it.
See [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#generating-urls) documentation entry.

If you want to generate a relative URL simply use:

```
$url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_profile_edit');
```

if you however want to generate an absolute URL you want to use this:

```
$router = $this->container->get('router');
$url    = $router->generate('blog_show', array('slug' => 'my-blog-post'), true);
//--------------------true outputs an absolute URL-------------------------/\
// http://www.example.com/blog/my-blog-post
```

Also taken from the documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#generating-absolute-urls)

`generate()` - as already mentioned here - takes 3 parameters.

- route name
- parameters of the route like `/blog/{page}` where page should be replaced by e.g. 1
- boolean true/false whether the generated URL should be absolute or not

Just mentioned `generateUrl()` because it equals the `{{ path(...) }}` function in Twig.

Answer (score 0):

```
__FILE__
```

Will get you the absolute path of the current file.

Comment: Thanks I understand,but what I want to know is about symfony2.My quesion was not good shape,I rewrote.

Answer (score 0):

It takes a little hunting, but you can actually track this down pretty easily.

1. Find where the `path` function is added to Twig:  [/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Extension/RoutingExtension.php#L39](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Extension/RoutingExtension.php#L39).
2. Examine the [getPath](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Extension/RoutingExtension.php#L43) function.  Observe that it uses the `$this->generator` object which is passed in with the constructor.
3. Find where this extension is loaded in: [/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Resources/config/twig.xml#L81](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Resources/config/twig.xml#L81)

We now know that we can call `$this->container->get('router')` to get the `generator` used in the `getPath` method, and therefore our code ends up looking something like:

```
$this->container->get('router')->generate($name, $parameters, $relative ? UrlGeneratorInterface::RELATIVE_PATH : UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_PATH);
```